# Check for whole and exact word match

Tags: javascript

I want a code to check whole and exact word match :)

So `look` is not matching `looked` in my logic.

```js
let speech = "you ever looked at someone";
let a = "look";

if(speech.includes(a)){
  console.log("Whole Word Matches")
} else {
  console.log("No Match!")
}
```

How can I modify the code above to check the whole word match

Comment: that's a task for old good regex. Grab a book and learn about Regular Expressions and try `/\blook\b/gi`

Comment: [This is the list of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Check+for+whole+and+exact+word+match+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com) when searching for the exact title of your question. Please read:[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use regular expression **(\bregExp\b)** to find the exact match of the word.

```
The \b metacharacter is used to find a match at the beginning or end of a word.
```

```js
let speech = "you ever looked at someone";
let a = "look";

if(new RegExp("\\b"+a+"\\b").test(speech)){
  console.log("Whole Word Matches")
} else {
  console.log("No Match!")
}
```

Comment: code-only answers are not helpflu, you should include some explanation in your answer

Answer (score -1):

```
if(new RegExp("\\b"+a+"\b").test(speech)){
 console.log("Whole Word Matches")
} else {
  console.log("No Match!")
}
```